# How do I access lower level variables and concat them when importing with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

I am looking at the following json file:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "Date": "2021-01-29",
            "Rating": 1018.81,
            "League_points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Columbus Blue Jackets",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/columbusBlueJackets.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference Winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2021-01-29",
            "Rating": 976.12,
            "League_points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Chicago Blackhawks",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/chicagoBlackhawks.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference Winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
```

and trying to import it into an HTML table with the following function :

```
function getStandings(){
    var date = document.getElementById("standingsDate");
    var path = "data/NHL/DataForNHL_" + date.value + ".json";
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        paging: false,
        destroy: true,
        "ajax": path,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Rating" },
            { "data": "League_points" },
            { "data": "Team.Logo"},
            { "data": "Division" },
            { "data": "President's Trophy" },
            { "data": "Playoff Qualifier" },
            { "data": "Conference Winner" },
            { "data": "Stanley Cup" }
        ]
    } );
    
    setTimeout(myFunction, 100)
    

    obj = document.getElementById("example_filter");
    obj.remove();
} );

}
```

The problem I am facing, is that instead of importing just Team.Logo, I would like to import it so that it displays Team.Logo, Team.modification and Team.Team in the same table cell of the column. Can anyone show me if this is possible?

Please let me know if more information is needed, thanks in advance!

Comment: Play with the column render callback. It exposes the row data and lets you build what you need out of it for that specific column

Comment: You can see some examples here: [`columns.render()`](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Functions). Specifically, in the "Transforming data" example, look at `render: function ( data, type, row ) { ... }`. If you define the column data as `{ "data": "Team"}`, then the function's `data` variable gives you access to the 3 values you want to assemble into one table cell.

Comment: @andrewjames that looks like exactly what i'm looking for. But when i try to integrate the function, it just says unexpected token. I'm not sure where to put the function to make it work. I tried after the ajax code, after the Team data row... Does anything need to be quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```js
{ "data": "Team.Logo"},
```

Use this:

```js
{ 
  "data": "Team",
  "render": function ( data, type, row ) { 
    //console.log( data )
    return data.Logo + ' ' + data.Team + ' ' + data.modification;
  }
},
```

This renders a cell as:

```html
<td>
  <img src="img/NHLpics/chicagoBlackhawks.gif" style="height:40%; width:40%"> Chicago Blackhawks +-diff
</td>
```

Of course, you may wish to change the layout from the one I have used.

---

You can see some more column renderer examples here: [`columns.render()`](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Functions).

Specifically, in the "Transforming data" example, look at `render: function ( data, type, row ) { ... }`.

More detailed syntax documentation can also be found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

Comment: amazing, thanks. I was so close but did not enclose the render in the same curlies as the data. It works perfectly now.